# Cabal usage (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, dependencies, installation, cabal, hackage

Cabal has dependency problems *constantly*. It's really tiring. So far I have tried to get many things working, here's my trying to install snap:

```
$ sudo cabal install snap-server
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: cannot configure ListLike-1.1.0. It requires mtl >=1.1.0 && 1.2
For the dependency on mtl >=1.1.0 && 1.2 there are these packages:
mtl-1.1.0.0, mtl-1.1.0.1, mtl-1.1.0.2 and mtl-1.1.1.0. However none of them
are available.
mtl-1.1.0.0 was excluded because mtl-2.0.0.0 was selected instead
mtl-1.1.0.0 was excluded because monads-fd-0.1.0.3 requires mtl ==2.*
mtl-1.1.0.1 was excluded because mtl-2.0.0.0 was selected instead
mtl-1.1.0.1 was excluded because monads-fd-0.1.0.3 requires mtl ==2.*
mtl-1.1.0.2 was excluded because mtl-2.0.0.0 was selected instead
mtl-1.1.0.2 was excluded because monads-fd-0.1.0.3 requires mtl ==2.*
mtl-1.1.1.0 was excluded because mtl-2.0.0.0 was selected instead
mtl-1.1.1.0 was excluded because monads-fd-0.1.0.3 requires mtl ==2.*
```

I have similar problems installing Happstack, etc. What is the procedure to make cabal...work?
I've already tried:

```
export PATH=/home/user/.cabal/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that snap-server-0.2.15 has an unbounded dependency on monads-fd.  The most recent version, monads-fd-0.1.0.3, requires mtl-2.*  Unfortunately this conflicts with the dependency on ListLike (via iteratee), which requires mtl < 2.0.  Both of these constraints can't be fulfilled simultaneously, so cabal gives up.

Try running `cabal install snap-server --constrain="monads-fd=0.1.0.2"`.  That will force an earlier version of monads-fd that doesn't require mtl, and I think everything will work properly.

If you're having problems with a lot of packages, it's probably due to the new `mtl` that was recently uploaded.  You can try adding `--constrain="mtl<2"`, which might help.

Moral to maintainers: follow the Haskell PVP and **always** use upper dependency bounds.

N.B. Even if I do upload a new ListLike that works with mtl-2 (which I'll do very soon), that won't fix your problem because the new ListLike won't be selected due to the upper bound on iteratee.

Comment: "Even if I do upload a new ListLike..., that won't fix your problem"
Moral: never use upper bounds. Joke :)
Look like we need something more stable then hackage and less stable then HP. Something in between.

Comment: @Yuras, I agree (and I realized that upper bounds prevented one solution while I was typing). If hackage required upper bounds on everything, it would go a long way to improving stability.  The more I work with cabal and version numbers, the more convinced I am that autotools got it right.

Comment: Yikes, cabal requires a lot of knowledge about the packages to use! That makes me sad :-(

Comment: Although thanks to this, I was able to install by --reinstall ing all the dependencies that had been broken. Thanks!

Comment: distro packages - if they exist for your world - are hopefully the middle ground you seek